# how to fill circle with lines? (canvas ctx 2d)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Is there a way how to fill circle with lines, in same way as it shown in the picture, without math computations for x1y1-x2y2 points on circle body? I mean, something like configuration for gradient or anything else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code taken from [this mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createPattern#creating_a_pattern_from_a_canvas)

Result:

[image: striped circle]

```js
// Create a pattern, offscreen
const patternCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const patternContext = patternCanvas.getContext("2d");

// Give the pattern a width and height of 50
patternCanvas.width = 25;
patternCanvas.height = 25;

// Give the pattern a background color and draw an arc
patternContext.fillStyle = "white";
patternContext.strokeStyle = "green";
patternContext.lineWidth = 2
patternContext.fillRect(0, 0, patternCanvas.width, patternCanvas.height);
patternContext.moveTo(0, 0);
patternContext.lineTo(25, 25);
patternContext.stroke();

// Create our primary canvas and fill it with the pattern
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const pattern = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

// Add our primary canvas to the webpage
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

Comment: I found another solution (with math). Need to translate canvas into the center of circle, then rotate canvas for Math.PI/4 and after it you may draw horisontal lines (which is quite simple). After context restoration, it is shown with Math.PI/4 angle. However, thx for help!

Comment: @degr I thought that it's not what you want

Comment: I need just simple working solution. Forgot about ctx.rotate function completely, but clearly had in mind that there was something like a "background" (it was pattern, from your solution). Think it would be much harder without rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Without math

```css
canvas {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2svp.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="275.994" height="283.991"></canvas>
```

Comment: cool solution, but as I know I can't use transparent png images with canvas context. ahaha, crap, it is css, even not canvas contex.